# Comments getting removed mysteriously

Tags: support, flagging, comments

Yesterday I posted a comment under [Looking for scriptural reference of Shanta Durga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/49973/4732), asking OP about something that is related to the post there. After sometime when I went there to check if OP responded or not I could not find my comment. Clueless what has happened I posted that comment again.

Today, I find that the comment is not there too.

The comment was a question for OP to answer, it is related to the posts there and is perfectly polite too. So I would like to know how it is getting deleted?

EDIT:

I posted another comment few hours ago under this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/52140/4732. As I check now even that was deleted. It's clearly a relevant comment and is not breaking any COC but yet it got deleted.

What is the solution for this? Looks like any comment can be deleted in this manner without Mod's intervention.

Comment: It was flagged as NLN  and bot removed because of wording ig. See [Why did flagging a comment as obsolete quickly delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292969).

Comment: Oh very strange ... We have to frame our comments cautiously then .. anyway it was not NLN by any means @TheDestroyer

Comment: Yes. It doesn't look like NLN or at least contested. Even Mods can't undelete such comments.

Comment: Oh so this looks like a loophole which can lead to misuse of flagging privilege .. because comments which do not deserve deletion will be deleted because of this @TheDestroyer

Comment: @TheDestroyer See my update ... another comment got deleted too

Comment: ohh..just saw.. we will take action on this

Comment: Trigger words are matched in [user's name as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354689/824803).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [@TheDestroyer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/comments-getting-removed-mysteriously#comment11063_2378) , any comment if flagged goes through loads of regexes and we are not really sure which regex would have caused deletion.

But in your case, it might be the words "accepted" and "answer" which would have triggered the deletion.

Read this comment to get a gist of what really would have happened:

> I remember people misusing this Scunthorpe Problem in the SE system by flagging comments by moderators with the wording Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?" as no longer needed (the word "accept" in "acceptable"). It's better if it's fixed @FedericoPoloni. :) –
> [Bhargav Rao Aug 3, 2018 at 17:00](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305410/are-comments-which-respond-to-another-comment-deleted-by-single-flag#comment1027415_313205)

Comment: The comment says it's required to be fixed but obviously it's not yet fixed .. so how to prevent misuse of the flagging system like it happened here?

Comment: @Rickross one way is to raise a meta on MSE by specifying the cases where the regex implementation is improper. We can provide this HSE one as an example.

Comment: ... Or such situations might be avoided by writing "[This answer](link to other answer) found a reference of Shanta Durga..."

Comment: What if I make spelling mistakes like writing answ#r (or something else) for answer?

Comment: @Rickross well for fun I would try and see that. ;-)

Comment: But all that is about what precaution we can take while framing the comment .. what about taking actions on those who are misusing this loophole knowingly? Because if these flags were handled by Mods then they would have been rejected.

Comment: I would think of this way, is the comment which got flagged was worth keeping? If yes, report like you did. If not, I would care less. Or if you think this is super great loophole, then raise a bug/feature meta ticket on MSE. @Rickross . Till now there is no meta ticket on this issue. So it would be good to have one. But we are not sure till when this will be resolved.

Comment: You also have seen the comments .. obviously they are worth keeping ... otherwise no comments on this site are worth retaining .. So I would not think in your way ...